# HtmlAgilityPack select a specific number of nodes

Tags: c#, linq, dom, html-agility-pack

Consider the following C# statement that implements HAP to select some HTML nodes from a given website.

```
var nodes = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[contains(@class,'relatedProductsGrid')]//div[@class='product']//a");
```

On the given pages, the selectors return around 20 nodes for the page, and my question is, if I wanted to limit the amount of nodes it grabs, how would I do this?

So essentially, I want to "select 3 nodes instead of 20" but in the cleanest possible way, maybe there is a LINQ expression I could use to simply my request?

Thanks all

Comment: Simply add `.Take(3)` to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function in XPath to restrict the number of items, in the following way:

```
//ul[contains(@class,'relatedProductsGrid')]//div[@class='product']//a[position() >= 1 and position() < 4]
```